# Converting CarouselPage to CarouselView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

Is it possible to add direct content to a CarouselView in Xaml?

I need to convert an old CarouselPage to the newer CarouselView, but it looks like it must be data bound. But my content for each slide is entirely different and does not easily lend itself to an item template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="myCarousel" 
              x:Name="carouselPage"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" BackgroundColor="#000000">
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="#000000">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#000000">
            <Label Text="Lorem ipsum" />
            <ImageButton Margin="0,20" Source="btn_continue" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" Clicked="Go_Right" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="#000000">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#000000">
            <Button Text="X" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="Go_Home"></Button>
            <ImageButton Source="slider-2" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
            <Grid Margin="0,20" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ImageButton Source="btn_back" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="Go_Left" />
                <ImageButton Source="btn_close" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Go_Home" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

</CarouselPage>
```

I need to create a multi-slide carousel, where each slide has different content like above. How would I convert that using CarouselViews?

The problem I am having with the CarouselPage is that it does not always behave consistently, which is why I imagine they are slowly deprecating it.

Comment: My answer is not working for you ? You need something different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my content for each slide is entirely different and does not
> easily lend itself to an item template.

You need to create different DataTemplate for each slide and [Choose item appearance at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime), for example:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselViewDemos.Controls"
             x:Class="CarouselViewDemos.Views.HorizontalLayoutDataTemplateSelectorPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StyleATemplate">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="StyleBTemplate">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <controls:ContentSelector x:Key="myContentSelector"
                                             AmericanMonkey="{StaticResource StyleATemplate}"
                                             OtherMonkey="{StaticResource StyleBTemplate}" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myContentSelector}" />
</ContentPage>
```

And in code behind, use `DataTemplateSelector` to select different template for each slide:

```
public class ContentSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StyleATemplate{ get; set; }
    public DataTemplate StyleBTemplate{ get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if(item.style == A){
            return  StyleATemplate;
        }else{
            return StyleBTemplate;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to change the current page programmatically? private void RestartSlider(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carouselPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children[0];
        }

Comment: Yes, you can set the [current item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction#preset-the-current-item) in CarouselView.

Comment: @User970008 
Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can add different content on every view.

It's necessary to create a CustomViewSelector.

Check my GitHub for a full sample code https://github.com/georgemichailou/ShaXam

Pay attention to these files

https://github.com/georgemichailou/ShaXam/blob/master/ShaXam/UI%20Helper/CustomViewSelector.cs

https://github.com/georgemichailou/ShaXam/blob/master/ShaXam/MainPage.xaml

https://github.com/georgemichailou/ShaXam/blob/master/ShaXam/MainPage.xaml.cs (Line 17-25-27)